# Get firestore collections based on values in array list in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get firestore collections based on an array list.

**I need to get collection 'items' based on the array 'favourites' inside collection 'users'.**

Below are the two images of my database.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vmeom.png]
 [image: enter link description here]

Comment: do you have the value inside the array?

Comment: you need to get the array favourite at first then get item based on the favourites.

Comment: Yes, I have the 'items' document id's inside 'favourites' array of each user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
  onPressed(){
    Firestore.instance.collection("users").getDocuments().then((querySnapshot){
      querySnapshot.documents.forEach((element){
        List value = element.data["favourites"];
        Firestore.instance.collection("items").document(value[0]).get().then((value){
          print(value.data);
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

Query the collection users -> get the array favourites -> use the value inside the array in the `document()` method.

Comment: Hi, How can I modify it to get individual user's(Currently logged) favourites? In my database 'user' documents have id of each user.

Comment: Us the document id, the user ID also?

Comment: Check this https://petercoding.com/firebase/2020/04/04/using-cloud-firestore-in-flutter/

Comment: Currently 'users' document have ID's of currenspoding user.

Comment: Check the article above, there are many examples like that.