# Update document value in Firestore Cloud with Flutter, having only a unique key value of such document

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, cloud

I'm new to Cloud Firestore but already made some CRUD operations but now I'm really stuck with this thing.

Each document inside the 'tiposFrota' collection has a key 'nome:' with a unique value, no document will have the same value for the 'nome:' key.

[image]

The problem is, whenever the user adds another 'Truck' to some other collections I need to increment the value of 'qtde:' by one, and when they remove 'Truck' the program will increment the number by -1, working as a counter.

I managed to create an operation to update a key value, but only when you have the document id, but in this case the id is autogenerated because they may add or remove standard values from the 'tiposFrota' collection.

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
.collection('controladores')
.doc('contadores')
.update({'numFrota': FieldValue.increment(1)}),
```

I'm really stuck with this, if anyone could please help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Woah, managed to find a solution by myself, this post [Get firestore collections based on values in array list in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62356353/get-firestore-collections-based-on-values-in-array-list-in-flutter).

Since the 'nome:' value is unique for each document inside the 'tiposFrota' collection I can use the .where statement as a filter for said document, get the snapshot with all the documents (but only getting one, obviously) and use the 'forEach' method to create a function using the '.id' parameter when calling the document.

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
.collection('tiposFrota')
.where('nome', isEqualTo: carMake)
.get()
.then((querySnapshot) { 
  querySnapshot.docs.forEach((element) {
     FirebaseFirestore.instance
     .collection('tiposFrota')
     .doc(element.id)
     .update({
       'qtde': FieldValue.increment(1)});
  });
}),
```